# Learning javascript, can't figure out hide and show elements

Tags: javascript

EDIT- I would like to see it written in javascript, not jquery or a framework please.

I know that this is something easily accomplished with jquery, but I'd like to learn the javascript behind the magic, and have been reading Dom Scripting by Jeremy Keith.

I've gotten a ways through the book, but doing examples where you copy code is far different from trying to build something yourself.

Right now I'm trying to do something simple (for others): Hide a paragraph element when the header2 element above it is clicked. Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="contentArea">
        <h2><a href="#">heading for the articles</a></h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. </p>
        <h2><a href="">Second heading for the articles</a></h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. </p>
    </div><!-- END MAIN CONTENT ---------------->
```

I'm trying to figure out the steps necessary to accomplish it, and can't even really spell it out to myself in plain English, much less javascript.

I'm trying to create a block of code that would say "whenever an h2 element within the div with the id contentArea is clicked, find the next paragraph below it and hide it from view."

Comment: You could always read the jQuery source code to get an idea of how this would work: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
// Select all h2 which are inside contentAread
var elems = document.getElementById('contentArea').getElementsByTagName('h2'),
i;

// For each one
for(i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
   elems[i].onclick = function(){
        var sibling = this;
        // While there is another sibling
        while(sibling = sibling.nextSibling){
            // If sibling is a P tag
            if(sibling.nodeName == 'P'){
                // Hide it
                sibling.style.display = 'none';
                // Then exit the loop
                break;
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: Sorry, it had a couple typos. Works now.

Comment: Thank you very much. EDIT- why is i listed at the ends of elems?

Comment: @Squadrons i is listed, because it's good Javascript coding practice to only declare variables once in every scope. So instead of using the var keyword again I added it on as another variable. It would probably be more readable to add a newline in between. I'll edit my post for clarity.

Comment: @Alex Can you explain to me the advantages of addEventListener? I'm really clueless to it. Does it let you name your listener and add more listeners of the same type without conflict or something? Does it work in IE as well?

Comment: Awesome Alex, I was just trying to figure out how to do that with Paul's example, and this seems completely different. Learning a bunch just from two simple examples.

Comment: addEventListener is the W3C standard for adding events. IE uses addEvent to attach events. That is why using a framework like jQuery to abstract the intricacies is beneficial...

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah IE is always really annoying when trying to write cross browser code without a framework. It's nice to get away from the frameworks sometimes though and do some traditional DOM manipulation haha

Comment: Yes, not a bad thing to use frameworks - as long as you understand what's going on under the hood.

Comment: Alex, any idea why the second h2 in your example isn't returning false?

Comment: Figured it out; if the href in the a was blank, it wouldn't show the element. Filled the href with '#' and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an onclick attribute directly to the element:

```
&lt;h2 onclick="...">...&lt;/h2>
```

Here's a simple function to show or hide elements:

```
function showHide(el) {
  el.style.display = (el.style.display == 'none')? '' : 'none'; 
}
```

Use window.onload to attach a listener to the subject headings:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var el = document.getElementById('contentArea');

  if (!el) return;
  var els = el.getElementsByTagName('h2');

  for (var i=0, iLen=els.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    els[i].onclick = function() {
      var node = this;

      do {
        node = node.nextSibling;

        // Hide all the Ps
        if (node.tagName && node.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'p') {
          showHide(node);

        // Stop when get to next heading 2
        } else if (node.tagName && node.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'h2') {
          break;
        }

      } while (node.nextSibling)
    };
  }
};
```